# alinhamento do texto e de uma imagem

Tags: html, css, mobile

Alguém pode me ajudar com o posicionamento do texto? Eu gostaria que o texto fosse para debaixo da imagem quando a resolução fosse a de um dispositivo móvel com no **máximo 540px** de largura.

Segue o site:

http://casimirowebshare.000webhostapp.com/nutrirossio/quem_somos.php

Comment: Defina telemóvel.

Comment: Outra coisa, a página é PHP mas vc não colocou essa opção nas tags

Comment: com no maximo 540px de lagura isso é o que eu chamo de telemovel @LeoCaracciolo

Comment: Utilize o bootstrap no seu projeto, para deixar ele responsivo mais facilmente. http://getbootstrap.com/ Logo após, basta seguir esse exemplo aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/PKVza/2/

Comment: É isso que vc quer? Teste com desktop e um  dispositivo móvel   http://kithomepage.com/sos/quem-somos.php Veja essa solução na minha resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com um simples Javascript podemos ter o resultado esperado.

Basta substituir a linha

`<div class="produto_em_destaque" style="display: flex;width: 100%;">`

por esse javascript

```
<script>
    if (screen.width<540){
        document.write('<div>');
    }else{
        document.write('<div class="produto_em_destaque" style="display: flex;width: 100%;">');
                }
</script>
```

Comment: continua sem dar

Comment: Você fez teste usando http://kithomepage.com/sos/quem-somos.php No desktop e mobile com no máximo 540px? No meu celular deu certo! foi para baixo da imagem e no desktop ficou acima da imagem.

Comment: ta certo eu é que tava a testar a reponsividade no pc e nao dava mas dps passei para o mobila e ja deu obg

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o Media Screen para usar um CSS específico para a largura que você deseja.
Exemplo:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  span {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Lembrando que o código precisa estar abaixo do seu CSS utilizado na visualização de desktop.

[Fonte](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: eu ja utilizo o media screen o meu problema é conseguir alinhar o texto em baixo da imagem

Comment: Se você utilizar `display:block` e `width:100%` nos dois elementos, texto e imagem, vai funcionar.